# how can I put an imageand fill circle using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have the doubt, I put the image inside the circle but it repeats,
what am I doing wrong?

```
container.append('svg:pattern')
            .attr("id", "img_cirle")
            .attr("width", 50)     
            .attr("height", 50)    
            .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .append("svg:image")
            .attr("xlink:href", 'img/botonrojo.png')
            .attr("width", 50)  
            .attr("height", 50)  
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0);





container.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("r", 80)
        .style({"fill":"url(#img_cirle)","cursor":"pointer"});*/
```

Comment: For completeness sake, [here's an example of using your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/RgpVpUPNnuxzY9fYDZcr?p=preview) with the ideas in the linked answer.

Comment: thanks. i have solved (y)